# Ranking over 2 Columns- SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run a report on this database, and i can't figure out how I can come to the final result.  I Hope you can understand the question.

[image]

This is the ERD of the Datbase I'm working on. 
I need to generate a report to Rank movies based on the average rating per genre and per year.

Result should be something similar to this:

```
YEAR | Genre   | Movie Name | Rating | Rank 
2017 | Fantasy | Starwars3  | 5      | 1
2012 | Fantasy | Starwars1  | 4      | 2
```

The code i done so far looks something like this

```
SELECT f.year, g.name,f.title, AVG(rating), RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(rating))
FROM Film f
JOIN FilmGenre fg
ON (fg.filmid=f.id)
JOIN Genre g 
ON (g.id=fg.genreId)
GROUP BY CUBE (f.year,g.name)
```

Code give errors, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the errors as well!

Comment: @jarlh - Column _____ ( those not used in the group by)   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: MySQL does not support `over()`, nor `cube()` nor `rank()`. But it looks like you use Access.

Comment: Well... as the error states... when you have any aggregate function you can't include columns in the select list a) are not aggregated or b) are not in the `group by` (`f.title` being an obvious offender here).

Comment: @juergend I' m sorry, i mean  Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @JacobH So i need to add the title in the group by ?

Comment: Yes, title needs to be in the group by OR it needs an aggregate function in the select. If you can't do either, you can workaround by writing another query to JOIN this query to the original table so you can include the title.

Comment: OVER (PARTITION BY f.year, g.name ORDER BY avg(rating) )

Comment: @JacobH Sorry but i didn't understand your answer :(

Comment: you want two different things simultaneously. You are trying to get the avg rating by year,name and title and you a rank over by order. You probably should try over (partition by year,name,title order by avg(rating)

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Should i store the average rating in a table and select it ?

Comment: @TonyDong tried it but no success

Comment: What would really help here is some sample data and table structures. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And please avoid comments like "Code give errors". That is useless. If you get errors, share the error message. Don't make other guess.

Comment: First get the avg working to your satisfaction then put it in a CTE (with ...) then do a select off the CTE and use rank if its appropriate to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your sample results, you would seem to want:

```
SELECT f.year, g.name, f.title, f.rating),
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rating DESC) as ranking
FROM Film f JOIN
     FilmGenre fg
     ON fg.filmid = f.id JOIN
     Genre g 
     ON g.id = fg.genreId
GROUP BY f.year, g.name, f.title, f.rating;
```